# MySQL .NET using DataSet

Tags: .net, mysql, dataset

```
Dim update_status = False

Dim tableName = "SF6SETUP"

Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(cs)
Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter()
'Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SF6SETUP")
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()

' Open connection as late as possible to get data.
conn.Open()
da.SelectCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SF6SETUP")
da.SelectCommand.Connection = conn

da.Fill(ds)

' Make a change to some row then update it.
ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("O2AreaCts") = "73333337"
ds.AcceptChanges()

da.Update(ds)

conn.Close()
```

Can someone please help me figure out what am I doing wrong. I get no error. No changes made in the table.

Why ?!!!

Comment: Do you need to set the UpdateCommand as well? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqldataadapter.html#connector-net-examples-mysqldataadapter-updatecommand

Answer (score 1):

`AcceptChanges` only updates the rows in the DataSet(in memory). It the changes the state to `unchanged`. If you want to update your rows to the database, call your `TableAdapter's` `Update` method. This method will call `AcceptChanges` implicitely.

```
ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("O2AreaCts") = "73333337"
ds.AcceptChanges()  ' this will prevent the update in the next line '
da.Update(ds) ' this would call AcceptChanges implicitely after the database was updated '
```

Note that you don't need to open/close the connection when you use a `DataAdapter`. It will be opened/closed in the `Fill` method.

Apart from that you have not provided an [UpdateCommand](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqldataadapter.html#connector-net-examples-mysqldataadapter-updatecommand) for the `DataAdapter` as Christopher has already mentioned. But that would be the next problem since you normally would [get an exception when it's missing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update.aspx).

You can use [`DataSet.GetChanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4ey25we.aspx) to get all changed rows. I assume that this returns nothing.

**Edit**: Ok, here's an example to show how to provide an `UpdateCommand` (assuming that you have an ID column)

```
  ' Create the UpdateCommand.
  Dim sql = "UPDATE SF6SETUP SET O2AreaCts=?O2AreaCts WHERE id=?oldId"
  da.UpdateCommand = New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
  da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("?O2AreaCts", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "O2AreaCts" )  
  da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("?oldId", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "id")
```

Comment: Hello Tim. I removed ds.AcceptChanges() and only left da.Update(ds) still nothing has happen. No changes made to the table and no errors again.

Comment: @mike: What does `ds.GetChanges` return before the update, nothing? Apart from that, you should provide an UpdateCommand for the DataAdapter. I've missed tha point in my answer. But that would be the next problem since i assume that there are no changes, otherwise you would get an exception for the missing UpdateCommand. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update.aspx

Comment: Looks like it is null. What I am trying to do is get DataSet make changes in it and then use that DataSet to update MySQL.

Comment: Additional information: Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows.

Comment: conn.Open()

    ' Open connection as late as possible to get data.

    da.SelectCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SF6SETUP", conn)

    da.Fill(ds)

    'ds.Rows(0).Item("Title") = "73333337"

    ' Make a change to some row then update it.
    ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0) = "73333337"

    Try
      da.Update(ds)
    Catch ex As MySqlException
      MessageBox.Show(e.ToString())
    End Try

    conn.Close()

Comment: @mike: You could have been more specific, what error? Anyway, as i've said, you must provide an update command first.

Comment: This is an error I get: Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows.

Comment: @mike: There you are. Now you only need to provide that update command. I've provided a link in my answer.

Comment: Ok where do I provide an Update command? I am trying to do a line: ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("H2AreaCts")="SOME NUMBER HERE" after that statement so the DataSet is updated. Then I call da.Update(ds) updating MySqlDataAdapter with a new modified dataset which crashes the program. Where should i put the Update?

Comment: @mike: edited my answer. You need to use the correct fields and dbtypes.

Comment: Maybe the reason my table does not work is it does not have a primary key or any key or any id. It only has Columns and then data. So what I was trying to do is read THE WHOLE TABLE IN modify the value and put THAT WHOLE TABLE BACK! It looks like for it to make it work I HAVE TO HAVE A PRIMARY KEY in my table but I can't have it there can't modify the structure of the table only the values.